# jquery addClass, attr issue with IE 9

Tags: jquery, dom

Below code doesnt give any issue in all browsers except IE 9.

IE 9 stops working in below code.

```
$( '#my_div_'+intSubModuleId ).prev( '.menu-custom-3' ).addClass( 'disabled' ).attr( 'title', 'Disabled' );
```

Will please someone explain the season and solution of this.

Sometimes I get res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm this in address bar.

Comment: whats the error in console?

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: Sometimes I get this in my address bar res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm

Answer (score 0):

IE don't understands method api chaining very well some times. Try to break it down into variable and then try

```
var domElement=$( '#my_div_'+intSubModuleId ).prev( '.menu-custom-3' );
domElement.addClass('disabled');
```